# Добавить скрипт при переходе на страницу с конкретной ссылки

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть сайт, который состоит из 2-х страниц. На первой странице есть ссылки, которые ведут на вторую страницу:
 - `<a>Ссылка 1</a>`
 - `<a>Ссылка 2</a>`
 - `<a>Ссылка 3</a>`
На второй странице есть блок меню, который состоит из 3-х кнопок, и блоки текста соответствующие каждой кнопке. Изначально видно только первый блок текста `display:block` с помощью css класса `visible`, остальные изначально `display:none`. При нажатии на кнопки меню отображается соответственный блок текста, а предыдущий скрывается(реализовано через js).

Я хочу сделать чтобы при нажатии на `<a>Ссылка 2</a>` открывалась 2-я страница моего сайта и класс `visible` был присвоен второму блоку текста, вместо первого. Например инициировать событие через js - клик по второй кнопке в блоке меню.
Можно ли как-то отследить по какой конкретно ссылке перешли на вторую страницу?

Comment: копайте в сторону cookie, localStorgae или sessionStorage

Comment: Можно в ссылке указать какую либо метку, выглядеть это будет так
 **site.ru/index.php#first** а получить доступ можно через window.location.hash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо Hills of Eternity.

В ссылках передал метку в виде `<a href="http://site.com/page-2#метка">Ссылка 2</a>`
И уже на второй странице получил значение метки через `window.location.hash` и вызвал событие на интересующий меня элемент.